# Iterating over Json collection using JQuery iterates over chars of the data string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, iteration

I am using ASP.MVC 1 to return an IEnumerable of objects (say, Cars):

```
public class Car : Entity<Car>
{
    public virtual string Make { get; set; }
    public virtual double Length { get; set; }
    public virtual string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult GetRoutes()
{
    IEnumerable<Car> cars = _carTask.GetCars();
    return Json(cars);
}
```

In my page, I want to iterate over each car returned, so I have this:

```
$.post("/Home/GetCars", null, 
    function(cars)
    {
         alert("type of object returned is " + typeof cars + ", content is " + cars);
         $.each(routes, function()
         {
              alert(this);
         });
    }
);
```

When I run this, the first alert box says:

type of object is string, content is [{"Make":"BMW"}, {"Make":"Ford"}]

Which tells me I am getting a string back (shouldn't i get an object back?), containing a Json structure with 2 objects. However the jquery $.each function then proceeds to iterate over each char in the string, so I get 46 alert boxes: the first says '[', then '{', then '"', then 'M', then 'a', then 'k'... you get the idea.

From what I have read, jQuery should be parsing this as a collection, and should iterate only twice to show me to alerts, one for each car. I could then do alert(car.Make) to display the makes, but if I try that I get undefined (because a string doesnt have a Make property).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help, there must be an obvious error but i promise I have done plenty of googling first and came up with nothing! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the type "json" as the last parameter in your $.post() method. Also, I think you can simplify your each statement:

```
$.post("/Home/GetCars", null, 
    function(cars)
    {
         $(cars).each(function() {
             alert(this); //this should point to the car. 
         });
    },
   "json"
);
```

Comment: i tried to use your code,

when the collection have one element it's work well.
but when the collecion have more then one value, 
the callback function dosnt executed

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell jquery to interpret the results as json. By default $.post just returns a string of the data. You can use one of the following options. Then when you iterate they'll be objects.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

Or add "json" as the last parameter to post

Comment: You got the same answer as Nick but he got there first so I marked his as the answer :( Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

[link text](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each#objectcallback)

```
$.post("/Home/GetCars", null, 
    function(cars)
    {
         $.each(cars, function() {
              alert(this.Make);
         });
    },
   "json"
);
```

Comment: Thanks I was missing the "json" (Tried once, didn't work, then I re-read the replies and realised I had it in the wrong place, after the $.each call)